Ideal multiplicative depth for a generic Levelled CKKS scheme
If I need to implement a generic hardware accelerator for the Levelled CKKS scheme (no bootstrapping supported), what would be the ideal multiplicative depth I should support? - that can support a variety of applications

CKKS stands for the scheme proposed by Jung Hee Cheon, Andrey Kim, Miran Kim, and Yongsoo Song in Homomorphic encryption for arithmetic of approximate numbers in proceedings of AsiaCrypt 2017 (open access).

There is no ideal, it is depends on your application.
